# No pages of output

Tags: macros, tex-core

The following plain TeX manuscript produces (with pdftex) no pages of output and no errors.

```
\def\mac.#1 #2.{#1}%
\mac. a b.%
\bye
```

Why?

I expect it to produce one page of output with the text

> a

If I change the manuscript by replacing the macro's body with `Hello, world!`, the manuscript produces the expected result: one page of output with the text

> Hello, world!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a space after your `.` here: that's important. TeX is looking for the shortest match to the argument spec, which it can achieve by `#1` being empty and that space being the one between `#1` and `#2`. The latter is thus '`a b`' (you can see that with for example `\showtokens` or `\tracingall`).

Only *one* parameter in a continuous set can be empty, so with

```
\def\mac.#1#2 #3.{#1}%
```

`#1` is `a` (with the space discarded) and you get the output you expect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64161/discussion-between-joseph-wright-and-evan-aad).